# Handling loops in AHK script

Tags: autohotkey

I've been thinking - what is the best way to handle loops in ahk script?

For example instead of:

```
; Collect results 1
Sleep 1000
Addr1 := IE.document.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innertext
String_Object := StrSplit(addr1, "`,")
If (Substr(Addr1, 1, 2) = "MK")
{
Addr1 := String_Object[2] . "," . Trim(String_Object[3]) . "," . PostCode
MsgBox, %Addr1%
}
Else
{
Addr1 := String_Object[1] . "," . Trim(String_Object[2]) . "," . PostCode
MsgBox, %Addr1%
}


; Collect results 2
Sleep 1000
Addr2 := IE.document.getElementsByClassName("name")[1].innertext
String_Object := StrSplit(addr2, "`,")
If (Substr(Addr2, 1, 2) = "MK")
{
Addr2 := String_Object[2] . "," . Trim(String_Object[3]) . "," . PostCode
MsgBox, %Addr2%
}
Else
{
Addr2 := String_Object[1] . "," . Trim(String_Object[2]) . "," . PostCode
MsgBox, %Addr2%
}
```

I'd like to do something like this (note this is pseudocode):

```
j = 0
i = 1
while (i <= 5)
{
Sleep 1000
Addr[i] := IE.document.getElementsByClassName("name")[j].innertext
String_Object := StrSplit(addr[i], "`,")
If (Substr(Addr[i], 1, 2) = "MK")
{
Addr[i] := String_Object[2] . "," . Trim(String_Object[3]) . "," . PostCode
MsgBox, %Addr[i]%
}
Else
{
Addr[i] := String_Object[1] . "," . Trim(String_Object[2]) . "," . PostCode
MsgBox, %Addr[i]%
}

j = j+1
i = i+1
}
```

Is it possible to accomplish this in AHK?

Comment: Please elaborate (in words) on what you're trying to achieve. That pseudo-code isn't really telling me anything. Btw: You should really work on your variable naming style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're looking for are Loops and A_Index.

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Loop.htm

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Index

A_Index automatically tracks the current loop iteration of the loop in which it exists; it is unique to its loop, and nested loops will track their own A_Index. For an easy example, try the following code:

```
Loop, 3
{
    MsgBox, Outer-loop %A_Index%
    Loop, 3
    {
        MsgBox, Inner-loop %A_Index%
    }
}
```

Based on your pseudocode, you would something to the effect of the following:

```
Loop, 5
{
    Sleep 1000
    Addr[A_Index] := IE.document.getElementsByClassName("name")[A_Index - 1].innertext
    String_Object := StrSplit(addr[A_Index], "`,")
    If (Substr(Addr[A_Index], 1, 2) = "MK")
    {
        Addr[A_Index] := String_Object[2] . "," . Trim(String_Object[3]) . "," . PostCode
        MsgBox, %Addr[A_Index]%
    }
    Else
    {
        Addr[A_Index] := String_Object[1] . "," . Trim(String_Object[2]) . "," . PostCode
        MsgBox, %Addr[A_Index]%
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I did not know about the A_Index automatic variable, the docsare impenetrable. +1 sir!